# Can't push to github with working ssh-key

Tags: git, github, push

This code:

```
sudo git push -u git@github.com:myusername/wolke master
```

give me this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I checked my ssh-key. It is the same like in github.

How to check If the repository exists? I init a repository with git init, so it should exist.

What else can I do?

Solution:
Don't use sudo!

```
git push -u git@github.com:myusername/wolke master
```

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you're using sudo, git is running as root and thus uses root's ssh keys. Without sudo you're using your own keys, so everything works as expected.